# How to force Eclipse CDT MinGW toolchain to use mingw32-g++.exe?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse CDT and MinGW to do C development on Windows 8.1.

I have unpacked company internal MinGW package and just copied it to `c:\MinGW`, so it was not installer. I also added `c:\MinGW\bin` to path.

When I run Eclipse CDT, it does detect MinGW toolchain. However, after I set up a C project and tell it to use MinGW toolchain, and build it, I see in the console output the C compiler used is `gcc`, and I would like to use `mingw32-g++.exe`.

How do I define this in Eclipse CDT?

I checked project `Properties\C C++ Build\Tool Chain Editor\` and under `used tools` I see the following:

- GCC Assembler
- GCC Archiver
- GCC C++ Compiler
- GCC C Compiler
- MinGW C Linker
- MinGW C++ Linker

Comment: Why would you want to use C++ compiler to compile C file? Please [edit] your question and be more clear about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is defined under project properties `\C C++ Build\Settings\Tool Settings`. Here one should select `GCC Compiler` and specify `mingw32-g++` or just `g++`, or whichever compiler is desired.